# How to find if a callback is a specific method?

Tags: php, function

At one point I have:

`$callback = array(&$this, 'foo');`

How can I find out later if `$callback` is the foo method?

`if($callback == array(&$this, 'foo'))` doesn't seem to work

Comment: It's working for me.  Can you include more of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callbacks are just simple arrays, and the method name is a string. Just check the second element of the array:

```
if ($callback[1] == 'foo')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
class A
{
    public function Test1()
    {
        $callback = array(&$this, 'foo');
        var_dump($callback == array(&$this, 'foo'));
    }

    public function foo()
    {
    }   
}

$a = new A();
$a->Test1();
?>
```